# Calling function with delay crashing application

Tags: c++, vector, lambda, move

I need some help with passing a lambda function to this class constructor as a parameter. I then want to push it into a vector and have the function 'run_funcs' call it with a delay then erase it from the global vector. Problem is, it's crashing and idk why. Any help is appreciated. Note: I am limited to C++03.

```
class CallFuncDelay {
public:
    CallFuncDelay(std::int32_t time, std::function<std::noreturn_t()> func);

    static void run_funcs();

    std::int32_t timer_iterator;
    std::int32_t delay;

    std::function<std::noreturn_t()> func;
};

std::vector<CallFuncDelay> function_container;

CallFuncDelay::CallFuncDelay(std::int32_t time, std::function<std::noreturn_t()> func) {
    this->delay = time;
    this->func = std::move(func);

    function_container.push_back(*this);
}

void CallFuncDelay::run_funcs() {
    if (function_container.size() == 0) {
        return;
    }

    for (auto it = function_container.begin(); it != function_container.end(); it++) {
        if (it->timer_iterator++ > it->delay) {
            it->func();

            function_container.erase(it);
        }
    }
}

int main(void) {
    CallFuncDelay::CallFuncDelay(20, []() {
        std::printf("hello :)\n");
        });

    while (true) {
        CallFuncDelay::run_funcs();
        ::Sleep(4);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The code modifies the container while iterating through it. That has to be done delicately. In this case, don’t remove the function pointers one by one. After running them all, clear the vector.

Comment: You should not increment `i` after erase, use its returned iterator. Incrementing the erased iterator is UB: [Invalidates iterators and references at or after the point of the erase, including the end() iterator.](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/erase). The proper use of erase is shown in the example there.

Comment: Read about [`std::priority_queue`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/priority_queue). It’s a much better fir for these requirements.

Comment: Out of curiosity: What compiler on what platform do you use which limits you to C++03?

Answer (score 0):

```
function_container.erase(it);
```

`function_container` is a `std::vector`. `erase()`ing a value from the vector invalidates the value's iterator. This `it` is no longer valid when `erase()` returns, automatically.

```
... ; it++)
```

Immediately afterwards, this invalid iterator gets incremented. This is undefined behavior, and this is what results in your crash.

Use the replacement iterator that `erase()` returns, which ***already*** points to the next value in the vector. In other words: either `erase()` and take the returned iterator, ***or*** increment the iterator (if you're not going to use it for erasing).